# rstudio Remove characters from numbers in columns with condition

Tags: r

I have a column of screen resolutions with observations like 'IPS Panel Retina Display 2560x1600', '1440x900', 'Full HD 1920x1080', 'IPS Panel Full HD 1920x1080', etc. I want to separate them. I tried the gsub function but the result is to exclude the 'x' also and have the result for example 19201080. Can you help me with this?

Comment: What did you try exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
vec <- c('IPS Panel Retina Display 2560x1600', '1440x900', 'Full HD 1920x1080', 'IPS Panel Full HD 1920x1080')
strcapture("(.*)\\b([0-9]+)x([0-9]+)\\b(.*)", vec, proto = list(pre = "", x=0L, y=0L, post = ""))
#                         pre    x    y post
# 1 IPS Panel Retina Display  2560 1600     
# 2                           1440  900     
# 3                  Full HD  1920 1080     
# 4        IPS Panel Full HD  1920 1080
```

Comment: Thank you extremely much but after how I replace with 'x' x 'y'?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: I would like to create a new column with for example '2560x1600', '1920x1080', etc

Comment: I found it thank you again!!!